# How to find if a particular pasuk is used in davening

Tags: tefilla, tanach, quotations

My father is trying to find out if a pasuk is ever quoted in any davening and I don't know of a specific resource which would help in a search. Other than using ctrl-f after downloading each siddur/machzor, or running a Bar Ilan search while including the siddurim they have in the database, is there any place that catalogues every pasuk and where it is quoted?

And for the record, I am trying to avoid sending others on my own wild goose chase, but if you are interested, or happen to have an answer, here is my dad's question:

"I'm looking for [Isaiah 62](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1062.htm):1.  The only reference I can find is in one of the Selichot between RH and YK, but even there only part of the verse is quoted.  The part cited is the first part and I'm looking for one that contains the second half or the whole verse."

Comment: I assume he's aware that it's part of a haftorah (Netzavim), but is interested in the Siddur proper.

Comment: Apparently, the Women of the Wall prayer uses it but the underlying question still stands. http://womenofthewall.org.il/about/the-wow-prayer/

Comment: Apparently I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: Can I ask why?  The search for pasukim in tefillah is usually to see how Chazal understood it.  Usually the opposite is relevant - in tefillah if you're interested to know the source for what you're saying!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rabbi Re'uven Brauner wrote a pamphlet indexing verses used in prayer called "Shimush Pesukim" (in halakhah.com): http://halakhah.com/rst/pesukim.pdf

However, the specific verse you quoted is not found in that index (nor do I remember it), except for a haftarah.

Comment: Excellent find!

Comment: wow! Thanks! I'll pass this along to dear ol' dad.