# "For Zion's sake" - Where in the liturgy?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Is Isaiah [62:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15993#v1) found anywhere in the liturgy?  I seem to remember a reference or two in Selichot, but I can't find it there now, nor can I find it anywhere else.

Comment: Raichard Rosen, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Uncannily related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22343/1569

Comment: may I introduce "Dear Old Dad" to the assembled masses...

Comment: ["Apparently, the Women of the Wall prayer uses it".](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22343/how-to-find-if-a-particular-pasuk-is-used-in-davening#comment51040_22343)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the [Haftarah for Parshat Netzavim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=362) and that [of a wedding](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11972/759).